# Can't get java to match regex with matches()

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem where I'm trying to get a parameter to match the format 'Uddd' where 'U' MUST be the letter U and 'ddd' can be any 3 digits from 0-9.

My current code:

```
//borrow method
public boolean borrow(String borrowerID) 
{
    //if the borrower ID matches the format 'Uddd'
    if (borrowerID.matches("U([0-9]{3})"))
    {
       //if the status is available
       if (status == 'A')
       {
          this.borrowerID = borrowerID;
          this.status = 'O';
          this.dateBorrowed = currentDate;
          return true;
       }
       //is not available
       else
       {
          return false;
       }
    }
    //does not match format
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

For some reason it's not validating properly. When I tried inputting '1' as the parameter, it still returned true.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be possible for that method to return `true` if the input is `"1"`. I can only suggest you ensure you *are* passing in `"1"` and that the method is the one being called.

That can be done with a simple debug statement at the top, something like:

```
System.out.println ("Calling correct function with [" + borrowerId + "]");
```

at the start of the function.

I'd also suggest a bit of clean-up to make the function easier to code and read, along the lines of:

```
// borrow method
public boolean borrow(String borrowerID) 
{
    // Temp debug statement.

    // System.out.println ("borrow [" + borrowerId + "]");

    // "Not available" or "invalid borrower" means reject request.

    if (status != 'A')
        return false;

    if (! borrowerID.matches("U([0-9]{3})"))
        return false;

    // Okay to borrow.

    this.borrowerID = borrowerID;
    this.status = 'O';
    this.dateBorrowed = currentDate;

    return true;
}
```

This is a lot cleaner than all those `return-else-do-something` constructs, and it follows a "fail fast" paradigm.

Some people tend to dislike multiple return points but that's usually because they don't understand *why* they're considered bad (spaghetti code). With a short function like this, it doesn't pose a problem.

Comment: Hrmm, I think the problem is with my other sub-class then.

Also, I noticed that your conditional statements don't use any braces. Is this only possible for one-line conditional statements?

Comment: Also, if for example in your revised code it detects that status is not 'A' will it return false and then just stop the code there?

Comment: @antonlab, yes, if it's a single-line "block", you don't need braces. Also yes on the "return" will skip the remaining statements.

Answer (score 2):

I get good results with your regex : "1" -> false, "UU123" -> false, "U1234" -> false, "U132" -> true.

but you can use \d instead of [0-9] :

```
 borrowerID.matches("U(\\d{3})")
```

Answer (score 1):

actually that's not possible.when input 1 it won't return true but it return false.may be your status is equal 'A' that should be reason to return true

```
String borrowerID="1";    
boolean matches = borrowerID.matches("U([0-9]{3})");
System.out.println(matches);
```

output>>

```
false
```

if you only want to find is regex match or not then use this .or put a sout and check does status value.definitely it  should be A

```
if (borrowerID.matches("U([0-9]{3})")) {

  return true;

} else {

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issues with your `regex`

```
System.out.println("U888".matches("U([0-9]{3})"));
```

Output `true`

```
System.out.println("1".matches("U([0-9]{3})"));
```

Output `false`

Try `debug` your code, with few `breakpoint` inside your `borrow function`

You can also optimize your like

```
if (borrowerID.matches("U([0-9]{3})") && (status == 'A')) { 
      this.borrowerID = borrowerID;
      this.status = 'O';
      this.dateBorrowed = currentDate;
      return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

I don't understand onething, you are checking the `status` againist 'A' and inside assignin '0', does it make sense?(Anyway it's upto you)

Comment: Re the status, I would suggest that `a` was available and `o` was out, something that makes sense with the code if you think in terms of library books, for example. You're only allowed to borrow something that's available, and you're only allowed to borrow it if your ID is valid (you have a library card).

Comment: @paxdiablo  Sorry, I thought it as zero, anyway he can introduce a `boolean` or `enum` is a good choice and make more sense, why do you want to go for `A` and `O` that confuses new readers right?